# Could not set unknown property 's' for source set main of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceSet

Tags: java, android, android-layout, directory, kotlin-android-extensions

In android Studio, when i am trying to build the project then i am getting the problem 'Could not set unknown property 's' for source set main of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceSet.'
The unknown property is the java.srcDir s=[app/src/main/java] in the build.gradle file of app. the code of that file is given below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.admin.myprofile"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDir s =['app/src/main/java']
} }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.41"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a typo on `java.srcDir s =['app/src/main/java']`=>`java.srcDirs =['app/src/main/java']`